# How do I use iframe-resizer with a React JS Page As Content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, iframe-resizer

I have a host webpage with an iframe. I also have a child page, to embed in the host's iframe, that is a React application. I want the height of the iframe to be adjusted automatically as the child page changes.

I'm trying to use [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to resize the parent iframe. I know I need to include [iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js](https://raw.github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js) in the child page (my react application). I don't know where in my child React project I need to set certain parameters/call functions and where I should import this JS file.

I've tried following the instructions here and on certain tutorials online:
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

But it's always just how to implement it on the host page.

I already included the script in the host page:

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="https://myiframeurl.com" width="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mycmsurl.com/IFrameResizer/Javascripts/iframeResizer.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
jQuery('#my-iframe').iFrameResize({autoResize: true});
//]]></script>
```

How do I correctly include the iFrameResizer.ContentWindow in my child/embedded React project?

Answer (score 3):

For a parent react page, I have just put together an official react wrapper for iframe-Resizer that supports its full API.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer-react

Comment: Hey @David Bradshaw, this seems like a wrapper for the parent page. It doesn't seem like this helps make a child page that is a react app become resizable. Am I missing something?

Comment: This for the parent page, if the child page is a react app, but not the parent. Then you can just use the standard version of iframe-resizer

Answer (score 2):

For a child react app, it must import and bundle iframeResizer.ContentWindow from the react-resizer package.

To do this, first add react-resizer to your client app's packages.

```
npm i react-resizer
```

Then, in the root component of your app, import the code for the ContentWindow. So for example, if `App.jsx` is the root component in your app, modify it like the following:

```js
// App.jsx

import React from "react";
// ... other imports
import "iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow"; // add this
   
export default function App() { ... }
```

This will bundle the iframeResizer.contentWindow code with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Even I tried using iframe-resizer but there is always some scenario where it fails. So I wrote my own javascript to resize iframe and it works fine and there is no dependency on third party library.

```
  // region react lifecycle methods
  componentWillMount () {
    // Detect whether device supports orientationchange event, otherwise fall back to the resize event
    let supportsOrientationChange = 'onorientationchange' in window
    let orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize'
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('message', this.checkSender)
      window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, this.setIframeHeight)
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('message', this.checkSender)
      window.attachEvent(orientationEvent, this.setIframeHeight)
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.checkSender)
    let supportsOrientationChange = 'onorientationchange' in window
    let orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize'
    window.removeEventListener(orientationEvent, this.setIframeHeight)
  }
  // endregion

  // region custom methods.
  setIframeHeight = () => {
    try {
      let iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId)
      if (iframe) {
        let iframeWin = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow
        if (iframeWin && iframeWin.getElementById('root')) {
          iframe.style.height = iframeWin.getElementById('root').offsetHeight + 'px'
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Resizing method call', e)
    }
  }

  checkSender = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // error added or removed in iframe
    if (e.data.msg === 'validationChanged') {
      this.setIframeHeight()
    }
  }
  // end region
```

Here setIframeHeight is the main method to resize iframe. Rest is supporting code. You can use refer to that if you want.
Note:- Here message is events from iframe.

Comment: And this also works on third party pages? So basically you just created a new component and included setIframeHeight in main.js? Or how did you get it to work?

Comment: setIframeHeight works on any iframe.Yes. Call this function on initial load, and device orientation.

Comment: But this script has to be included on the host page, correct? So if my host page is a cms this will not work?

Comment: Consuming application will have this code to resize third party iframe. Its simple javascript should work in any environment where javascript is allowed.